# sudo apt-get update not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have been using ubuntu 13.04 in oracle virtualbox. The command `sudo apt-get update` is not working for me and is giving lot of 404 errors.I got stucked.

Here are my sources.list file entries

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail reached *end-of-life* on [January 27, 2014](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), thus is no longer supported by canonical and its repositories were removed from the archives.

You could try to fix the errors removing the lines from `sources.list` or replacing `raring` with `trusty` (Ubuntu 14.04) in the urls. These methods are discouraged because in one case you will not receive updates, and in the other you may install not compatible software and compromise the system.

You should should use Ubuntu 14.04, supported until April 2019. If for some reason you don't want to use that version, get Ubuntu 12.04 which is a *Long Term Support* and it's supported until April 2017.